# Name of set with Jordan measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

In German we have a special work for sets with Jordan measure zero: "Jordansche Nullmenge".

Does there exist a special name for such a set in English as well?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with this class of sets some (for example, the $\sigma$-ideal generated by them is a proper sub-$\sigma$-ideal of the $\sigma$-ideal of sets that are both Lebesgue measure zero and first Baire category), and I have not seen a consistently used standard name for them. Among the terms I've seen include: Jordan null, Jordan measure zero, Peano-Jordan null, Peano-Jordan measure zero, content zero, Jordan content zero, etc.

Your German version corresponds to "Jordan null set", and I suspect there are German versions in use for at least some of the other names I gave above.